# Phong shading blows out things close to white [OpenGL]; is there a way around this?

Tags: shaders, graphics, lighting

I'm doing per-pixel lighting using the Phong shading model.

In pseudo code this looks like:

```
vec4 ambientColor = light.ambientIntensity * material.diffuse;
vec4 diffuseColor = light.diffuseIntensity * material.diffuse;
vec4 specularColor = light.specularIntensity * material.specular;
finalColor = (ambientColor + diffuseColor + specularColor);
```

And you can add in a shadow map or light attenuation easily. Even color the light via the `light.xIntensity` values.

My problem is that I have a cloud texture that's all white values with varying levels of alpha. This is textured on a sphere. When rendering, what happens is that at the very appex of the light, i.e. the point closest to the light source the following seems to be happening:

1. When my `light.ambientIntensity` is at `0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2` I get an `ambientColor` on the whitest parts of the texture is say `0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2` and on the darkest parts of the texture could be `0.2,0.2,0.2,0.0`.
2. With a `light.diffuseIntensity` of `1,1,1,1` I will get `diffuseColor` ranging from `0,0,0,0` (when we're nowhere near the light, i.e. the other side of the sphere) through to `1,1,1,1` when we're on the tip closest to the light and the diffuse color of the material is also full white.
3. I can skip specular here. Because the end result is now `1.2,1.2,1.2,1.2`. The problem is that I'm now losing some detail because any values that *should* have been `0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8` are now full opaque white.

I understand that this would be desirable under some situations, like using HDR, but in this particular case it's not the result I want.

I'm using OpenGL 4.4 but I assume this problem and a solution is API agnostic.

Comment: how is `material.specular` calculated ?

Comment: I wouldn't say "calculated", it just has a value between 0 and 1 for each RGBA component. For the sake of argument, they're all the same value, i.e. `(0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3)` or `(1,1,1,1)` for each pixel. It's a specular map

Comment: i'm asking because this line at least `light.specularIntensity * material.specular` doesn't look right. is should be something like ` material.specular * pow(e_dot_l,light.specularIntensity)`. The same is for the rest of the illumination components , they should be calculated in a way, just a multiplication does't cut it.